# Force xcodebuild use a specific SDK only

Tags: install, xcode, homebrew, unix, compatibility

I am trying to fix a homebrew formula which uses `xcodebuild` to build a dependency. Unfortunately, this dependency relies on an older SDK, `MacOSX10.12.sdk`. I cannot make this project use a newer SDK as it would require vast refactoring to the codebase. Moreover, this library is from Apple and they chose to drop support for it on purpose in the newest Xcode SDK.

Fortunately, I have managed to find the SDK which I need from [this repository on  Github.](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs) Yet now I do not know how to force `xcodebuild` to use the SDK which I need. No matter what options or variables I set, `xcodebuild` always uses the default SDK from Xcode.

The version of the system I'm using for this is 10.12.6. Yes, even though the version of the system itself is 10.12, Xcode refuses to use an SDK which matches said version.

So how can I force `xcodebuild` to use my older SDK in my own custom directory?

Answer (score 1):

You run xcodebuild like this:

```
xcodebuild -sdk "/path/to/sdk/" -project myproj.xcodeproj
```

Comment: I have already tried the `-sdk` flag. `xcodebuild` still invokes `clang` with flags such as `-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk` and `-mmacosx-version-min=10.13`. It also invokes `libtool` with `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.13` and `-syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk`

Comment: Are you sure you haven't actually set those paths to the 10.13 SDK in the xcodeproj itself?

Comment: I am not sure about that. Where can I find those paths in Xcode?

Comment: In the build settings - but I would recommend looking at the Xcode project files with a simple text editor first to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It seems that you are right; the project settings try to always use the latest SDK & try to always deploy to the latest system version. Fortunately, `ilovezfs` (one of homebrew's maintainers) helped me to solve my problem without having to use an older SDK [by setting some environment variables.](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/19296#issuecomment-352867571) He explains it [here.](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/19296#issuecomment-352874177) I had already tried to do what he did, but I guess I screwed it up by trying to use an older SDK.

Comment: In any case, I found your answer helpful so I'll give you an upvote. Thanks!